# Jenkins pipeline console output verbosity

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to cut out some of the verbosity you get in the Jenkins console output?

This is my context.

I've configured the Kubernetes cloud on my Jenkins server and each time I run a job, I get a ton of output in the form of system configuration that I don't need. And it's consistent with every build run using the jnlp agent.

```
‘foo’ is offline

Agent foo is provisioned from template foo
---
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Pod"
metadata:
  labels:
    jenkins: "slave"
    jenkins/label-digest: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    jenkins/label: "foo"
  name: "foo"
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - "********"
    - "foo"
    env:
    - name: "JENKINS_SECRET"
      value: "********"
    - name: "JENKINS_TUNNEL"
      value: "1.2.3.4:50000"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_NAME"
      value: "foo"
    - name: "JENKINS_NAME"
      value: "foo"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_WORKDIR"
      value: "/home/jenkins/agent"
    - name: "JENKINS_URL"
      value: "https://example.com"
```

My base image is `jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4` I'm not passing any **Command to run** or **Arguments to pass to the command** in my Pod template.

So I'm a little curious as to where these extra logs are coming from.

I do expect and get the standard console output that is relative to the actual build and all, but I'd like to know how to get rid of these extra bits

Anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: Is your output desired output or output with `all unnecessary information`? What verbosity you have (what can be found in `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env` file)?

Comment: My output is the output with unnecessary information that I'm trying to get rid of. Plus I only get this additional output in jobs when I'm running the `jenkins jnlp agent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Jenkins version 2.378. Unfortunately disabling 'ShowRawYaml' under Kubernetes Pod Templates did not help. May be a bug.

Alternatively, i'm using below statement in the Pipeline of JenkinsFile. This is helping me disable Pod Log/Yaml display in Console Output. See pic attached for reference

showRawYaml 'false'

[Jenkins Pipeline snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccbhi.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable by doing this

Go to `Manage Jenkins -> Kubernetes Pod Templates or in a Kubernetes Cloud Configuration project` and expand your pod template and untick the option there `Show raw yaml in console`